# Strange CSS when adding a user to the people picker

Tags: 2007, people-picker

I have a problem happening on IE only when you put some name or add some name to the people picker. It will then validate and display users side by side. I think SharePoint injects the users using JavaScript.

Then the problem comes out of nowhere, a table (or div maybe) appearing like the attached image. Also, its resizeable.

[SCREENSHOT http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/1613/sssrq.jpg](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/1613/sssrq.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that you have some custom CSS in place because this won't happen by default.  It's hard to tell from your image, but the People Picker looks like it's not the normal size, so there's something custom.  I'd peel back those customizations and layer them back in one step at a time until I found where I was going astray.

Comment: Hi Marc! Thanks for your suggestion. 

Actually i've never specify such css style for the items inside the people picker. or the people picker textarea itself. :)

So what internet explorer will do is replicate its host width and height for each item inside the people picker. i pressume they're divs. ( only on internet explorer browsers, this didnt happen on other browsers ).

Comment: eg. you have a #content div which you specify 800px and 300px in height, which a form consisting of a people picker textarea. items inside people picker will replicate its style. so, for you guys! please dont specify height and width for containing div :D if you dont to get a mess like i did.

what i did is deleting external css stylesheets, and putting them back 1 by 1 ( inspired by marc's suggestion ). and later on i found its my div#content. :) solved under 5 mins.

Thanks to marc! :D